# Is Bayes' theorem necessary in this question?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The probability of rain during a winter day is 0.58, the probability of rain during a spring day is 0.38, the probability of rain during a summer day is 0.25 and the probability of rain for a fall day is 0.53. Each season is 1/4 of the year. What is the probability of rain on a randomly chosen day?
In this question I got a 0.435... But I'm not really sure if I used the Bayes' theorem. I know, however, that I used **the general multiplication rule and the law of total probability** because in order to get the probability that it rains for any given season, I have to use the multiplication rule. And then to get the total probability of rain on any given day (in all four seasons), I have to use the law of total probability.
Once more, is Bayes' theorem necessary/is used here? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need Bayes here.

Comment: Bayes's theorem is used for finding certain conditional probabilities. That is not involved here.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to calculate the average

$$\frac{58+38+25+53}{4}=43.5\%$$